# Show cell values for group rows in AgGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working with Ag-Grid enterprise and using the `rowModelType` as `serverSide`
I just want to show some custom value for the second and third column on the group row(marked in red line).
I have inspected the elements and there seems to be only 1 cell for the group rows which is for `Members` column in this case.
I have also tried to use [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocolumn-formatting?file=index.ts) example, using the `aggFunc` but that didnt work either.

My ColumnDefs is following:

```js
[{
    field: 'CALENDARYEAR',
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
  },
  {
    field: 'MONTHYEAR',
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
  },
  {
    field: 'Members',
    headerName: 'Members',
    width: 300,
  },
  {
    field: 'Column Name',
    headerName: 'Column Name',
    width: 240,
    valueFormatter: () => {
      return 'Date Value';
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'Members',
    headerName: 'Parent',
    width: 240,
    valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) => {
      return params.node ? .parent ? .key || 'None';
    },
  },
];
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you check groupUseEntireRow parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve that using the grid property `groupDisplayType` as `singleColumn`
It create a different cell for each column for the group rows as well.
Here is a working example of this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/jf8bctV8RmoWoMEh?open=main.js